Error: invalid environment block. 452: out of range pointer: 0xcfff020 Aborted. Press any key to exit
I was running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS with no problems backed up a disk image of it running Rescuezilla. Upgraded to the newer Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS but didn't like that some of the apps I had were not running right. So I restored the SSD drive using rescuezilla and now I have that message popping up. I have restored before and never had it come up. I also tried to reload the old 22.04.5 LTS from a USB and it fails to boot up giving me a Grub Rescue prompt.
If I hit any key. Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS does load successful but I now have to hit any key for it to boot up. How can I fix this so that hitting the power button only will load Ubuntu? And why am I getting this error when I restore a good copy of Ubuntu using Rescuezilla? Any help would be appreciated.
